# DMA to UART transmits only the first byte

Tags: msp430, dma

I am working on MSP430 Series Controller and I have a buffer to be sent on UART via DMA.

I am pasting my DMA configuration and Code snippet for more information.

```
DMACTL0 = DMA0TSEL__UCA0TXIFG;
DMA0SA  = &buff;
DMA0DA  = &UCA0TXBUF; 
DMA0SZ  = 64;                      // Block size in bytes
DMA0CTL = DMADT_1 | DMASBDB| DMASRCINCR_1 | DMAIE| DMALEVEL_L; // Rpt, inc
DMA0CTL|= DMAEN;
```

I am filling data as below.

```
   char buff[64];
   buff[0] = 0x64;
   buff[1] = 0x23;
   buff[2] = 0x65;
   buff[3] = 0x31;
```

When I initiate DMA transfer , The buffer got transfer but When I check on terminal , Its shows only the first value '0x64', Not other value.I am doing block transfer , so whole block should be transfered when dma initiated.
And in Interrupt routing i am reseting the dma flag.

My interrupt Handler.

```
 __interrupt void DMA_VECTOR_ISR(void)
 {
     DMA0CTL &= ~DMAIFG;
     DMA_Doneflag = 1;
 }
```

this DMA_Doneflag I have took as boolean volatile and that is reset when tx is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A block transfer indeed copies the whole block; it is the equivalent of the following:

```c
while (!(UCA0IFG & UCTXIFG)) {}  // wait for trigger
for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    UCA0TXBUF = buf[i];
```

This is not what you actually want. You need to wait for the trigger before each single byte:

```c
for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    while (!(UCA0IFG & UCTXIFG)) {}
    UCA0TXBUF = buf[i];
}
```

This can be done with the repeated single transfer mode (`DMADT_4`).

And you need `DMASRCINCR_3` to actually go through the buffer.

Comment: Hi @CL. , Thanks for your Reply, Yes I have tried that bit, and 4 bytes that I have assigned in buffer is going but, After the size is transferred , It stops, And I want to have transfer Continuously Running,
can you please guide me into this.

Comment: Are you aware of what you wrote in the last sentence of your question?

Comment: let me clear please, with the change you have suggested, is working fine. But on terminal I can only see the first byte of buffer repeatedly coming.
The other data in buffer is not transmitted. For that I have tried with `DMASRCINCR_3` (source inc.) but, after some time the transfer gets stopped. Than again I have to reset controller to begin transfer.
in my dma isr I am doing `DMA0CTL &= ~DMAIFG ` (inverting flag after trigger). 
am i mistaking here?

Comment: Edit your question to show the interrupt handler. And specify "some time".

Comment: "some time" is like after 7 or 8 transfer it stops.

Comment: Hi, I have Handled the transfer but I have had another problem. The transfer is happen on every time interrupt of 1s. And total of data transferred is of 2.4kB. But When I check on receiving end (on linux soc) I sometimes not getting as per size I have mentioned ( i.e 600 x4 buff) for every buffer. Instead I get correct size 4 to 5 times when i do transfer 20 times. The dma code remained same. Please tell me if more info required for solution.

Comment: can you comment on this :@CL.

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: HI @CL. Thank you comment., I have added question on below link,
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384704/facing-difficulties-in-data-transfer-over-uart-with-dma-on-msp430)